# Remove JLabel from array

Tags: java, arraylist, jlabel

```
List<JLabel> label = new ArrayList<>();
label.add( new JLabel( "E:\" ) );
label.remove( 0 );
```

Why i can't remove rekord from this list?

```
k = 0;

try {
    FileStore store = Files.getFileStore( Paths.get( label.get( k ).getText().toString() ) );
    max = Integer.parseInt( humanReadableByteCount( store.getTotalSpace() ) );

    if( max.equals( 0 ) ) label.remove( k );
} catch( Exception e ) label.remove( k );
```

This is my full code.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Nothing, this element just stay in there :/ label.size() == 1

Comment: Saved your source, recompiled, running the correct version?

Comment: But it doesn't: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/W6tFqP)

Comment: For example, i see debug information (simple system.out.println, before label.remove) but label.size is still the same.

Comment: I can not understand what the problem is, your code removes the element just fine.

Comment: Does your of statement get executed?

Comment: Please add any output from your program to the question; as well as the version of your code with `println`'s added.  I would also advise using your debugger to be extra sure that your code is being executed.